# Is there a built-in file buffering mechanism in fs module in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

(Please don't confuse it with the Buffer class, what I mean is file buffering, or file caching)

I have read the whole fs module page on NodeJS documentation. But I haven't found any mention about a way to specify a file buffer for it.

For example:

- In C/C++, you can use [setbuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/setbuf/) or [setvbuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/setvbuf/) function;
- In C#, the FileStream class has [certain constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_FileStream__ctor_System_String_System_IO_FileMode_System_IO_FileAccess_System_IO_FileShare_System_Int32_System_Boolean_) that allow you to set the buffer size, the class itself sets 4KB as the default buffer size.

So is there any equivalent in NodeJS world or I have to make my own?

Please note that I aware about [Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html), but I want the ability to [seek](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) backward and forward arbitrarily in a file (with the help of [fs-ext](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-ext) package).

**Edit**: This is what I want to achieve (using the sync methods of fs module):

```js
// open a file and create an underlying buffer for it, 4KB for example
let fd = fs.openSync(path, 'r+');

let b = Buffer.alloc(8);
// cache 4KB into the underlying buffer, take 4 bytes of it into b;
fs.readSync(fd, b, 0, 4);
// here the file pointer is still inside the underlying buffer range,
//  so we just take the next 4 bytes of it into b, without having to do I/O operation;
fs.readSync(fd, b, 0, 4);

// cache miss: seek very far from the start then read, fs module should read
//  ahead a new underlying buffer around the file pointer;
fs.readSync(fd, b, 0, 4, 1024*4+3);
// not a cache miss: seek a litle bit forward
fs.readSync(fd, b, 0, 4, 1024*4+4);
// not a cache miss: seek a litle bit backward
fs.readSync(fd, b, 0, 4, 1024*4+1);
// cache miss: seek a long way backward
fs.readSync(fd, b, 0, 4, 10);
```

Comment: May I ask what real world problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @lovelywib I'm trying to port 2 classes BinaryReader and BinaryWriter from .NET to NodeJS. The port is done but I just want to learn some more about this

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of `fs` module does mention buffer. However `seek` function is missing, so users would have to manipulate `position` parameter to achieve some tasks. see function defintion:

`fs.read(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, callback)`

example:

```js
var fs = require('fs'); 
  
fs.open('bigfile.txt', 'r', function (err, fd) { 
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  const buffer = Buffer.alloc(4096);

  fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, 4096, null, (err, bytesRead, buff) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(`bytesRead: ${bytesRead}`)
    console.log(buff.toString());
  });
});
```

Comment: It seems that there is a misunderstanding here, I means some kind of file buffer mechanism to reduce I/O operation and if NodeJS has any, not how to read from file into Buffer.

Comment: Hey @MeigyokuThmn, do you want to provide an expected nodejs code snippet you're trying to archive. To my understanding, setting buffer in the constructor or the I/O operation function is almost same thing. Under the hood, it is something similar to: loading bytes to buffer, reading buffer, then repeat.

Comment: There is none because like I wrote above, I can't find any built-in way that also supports seeking. It seems that I have to write a lib by myself.

Comment: I added an example, hopefully it will elaborate.